# Change position of navigationItem.title

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

In my ViewDidLoad I try something like that but its not working:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,2,60,14)];
label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresisingFlecibleWidth;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:label];
```

I want to display a label in the left part of my NavigationBar.
Or maybe change the navigationBar.title position

Thanks,

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do set navigation item's title view to UILabel with left text alignment:

```
UILabel* lbNavTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,40,320,40)];
lbNavTitle.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
lbNavTitle.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Hello World!",@"");
self.navigationItem.titleView = lbNavTitle;
[lbNavTitle release];
```

Created this way item's title also tolerates buttons on navigation bar and does not overlap them.

Comment: What if some one is having the rightBarButton? This will not work right?

Comment: why? it seems navigation item automatically shrinks its title view if left or right button is present. This approach works for me...

Comment: that works for me too. Or you can also try [self.navigationcontroller.navigationBar.topItem setTitleView:yourlabel];

Comment: It should be noted that the label's text alignment governs only the alignment *within* the label. The label itself is forced left by making its frame so wide as to consume *all* the empty space on the navBar. So that figure (320 in the example) must be exact. If it's too big and you add buttons to the right, you'll truncate the back button. And you must recalculate and adjust upon autorotation.

Comment: this fails on small devices as Wienke pointed out. should not be accepted because of hardcoded values.