# How to make iOS navigationItem.titleView align to the left?

Tags: ios, swift

```
navigationItem.hidesBackButton  = true
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil

head = UIView()
head.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 44)
head.frame.origin.x = CGFloat(0)
navigationItem.titleView = head
```

I attempt to align the titleView to the left, but it still remains in the middle.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513907/change-position-of-navigationitem-title

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
let title = UILabel()
title.text = "TITLE"

let spacer = UIView()
let constraint = spacer.widthAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
constraint.isActive = true
constraint.priority = .defaultLow

let stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [title, spacer])
stack.axis = .horizontal

navigationItem.titleView = stack
```

The idea is that main view (in this case `title`) will take all the space it needs and `spacer` view will take all the free space left.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer but Xcode gives me a warning `_NSLayoutConstraintNumberExceedsLimit` because of `CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude` is it possible to solve it ?

Comment: You can either use some hardcoded value, or something like this: `max(UIScreen.main.bounds.width, UIScreen.main.bounds.height)`

Comment: This breaks on iOS 16.0 but works on iOS 16.1.

Answer (score 7):

I figured it out.

I just need to set my custom UIView as the leftBarButtonItem.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar requirement of adding the Title along with the subtitle to the left of the navbar. I couldn't achieve it with a TitleView since it cannot be aligned left. 
So I took @TIMEZ and @Wain's answers, along with responses from the thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38626004/add-subtitle-under-the-title-in-navigation-bar-controller-in-xcode) and added a complete answer, in case it helps anyone :

```
let titleLabel = UILabel()
    titleLabel.text = "Pillars"
    titleLabel.textAlignment = .center
    titleLabel.font = .preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFont.TextStyle.headline)

    let subtitleLabel = UILabel()
    subtitleLabel.text = "How did you do today?"
    subtitleLabel.textAlignment = .center
    subtitleLabel.font = .preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFont.TextStyle.subheadline)

    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [titleLabel, subtitleLabel])
    stackView.distribution = .equalSpacing
    stackView.alignment = .leading
    stackView.axis = .vertical

    let customTitles = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: stackView)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [customTitles]
```

Answer (score 4):

If it's a custom UIView, override intrinsicContentSize and return

`CGSize(width: .greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric)`

This will stretch the view to the entire width between left and right bar button items.

Answer (score 2):

You can't align a title view to the left. You can create a title view and add a subview positioned to its left. If you're looking to display in place of the back button then you should be using a bar button item instead of title view.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Apple wants you to do that. Navigation bars have a pretty specific purpose that often involves having something else in the top left corner like a Back button. You might be better off making a custom UIView or UIToolbar that looks like the navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can constraint the titleView to the navigationBars leftAnchor.

```
 private func setupNavigationBarTitleView() {
        let titleView = YourCustomTitleView()
        navigationBarTitleView = titleView
        navigationBarTitleView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        navigationItem.titleView = navigationBarTitleView

        if let navigationBar = navigationController?.navigationBar {
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                titleView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationBar.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
                titleView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 36)
            ])
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to add low priority constraint for title width.

```
    let titleLabel = UILabel()
    titleLabel.textAlignment = .left

    ...

    let c = titleLabe.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10000)
    c.priority = .required - 1
    c.isActive = true

    navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys after trying most of the solutions above. I found that most of em still did not meet my prod requirements. Here is a solution I came up with after trying out different solutions.

```
func setLeftAlignTitleView(font: UIFont, text: String, textColor: UIColor) {
    guard let navFrame = navigationController?.navigationBar.frame else{
        return
    }
    
    let parentView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: navFrame.width*3, height: navFrame.height))
    self.navigationItem.titleView = parentView
    
    let label = UILabel(frame: .init(x: parentView.frame.minX, y: parentView.frame.minY, width: parentView.frame.width, height: parentView.frame.height))
    label.backgroundColor = .clear
    label.numberOfLines = 2
    label.font = font
    label.textAlignment = .left
    label.textColor = textColor
    label.text = text
    
    parentView.addSubview(label)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let navLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width - 32, height: view.frame.height))
    navLabel.text = "Hi, \(CurrentUser.firstName)"
    navLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    navLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
    navigationItem.titleView = navLabel
```